# Restrict folder access via a PHP checked Basic Auth

Tags: php, nginx, basic-authentication

Using Nginx and PHP, I want to protect the contents of a folder behind a username / password check.

On the frontend, I want to use HTTP Basic Auth instead of having to implement any kind of form.

On the backend, this check should be done with business logic, not a static htpasswd file (for example via a database or API).

In other words, the flow would be:

1. User hits protected file's URL
2. HTTP Basic Auth dialog is shown
3. PHP script runs to validate the credentials
4. If valid, the file starts downloading. Otherwise, a 403 is returned.

What is the simplest approach to achieve this?

(To be clear, I mostly want advice about configuring Nginx. The PHP logic beyond getting the credentials and returning the file is not my question here.)

Edit: I do not need or want to create a session at all. I don't mind the users entering their credentials every time for every file.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it using Nginx then it's just a case of adding a couple of [directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html) to the locations you want to restrict access to and setting the passwords, Nginx does the rest. The Nginx implementation uses a static file for passwords though.

For a solution more like the one you describe have a look at the examples in the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

Answer (score 0):

For Apache, the directory or location directive can be used to restrict access: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/protected">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Authentication Required"
  AuthUserFile "/etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd"
  Require valid-user

  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```